# form for updating google calendar

Tags: mysql, forms, google-calendar-api, gcal

I would like to be able to automatically update gcal from a form as follows:

A. On my form I enter the name and phone number of a person I want to stay in touch with over the course of the year (*jon smith 555.555.1212*). I want the posting to take the name and phone number, and  insert them into a MySQL table.  There, they are merged with the data from another table, which consists of 3 unique sequential follow-up events that are each 28 days apart based on the form submitted date:

1. jon smith 555.555.1212 + call for lunch meeting (28 days from initial post date)
2. jon smith 555.555.1212 + email info on topic of interest (56 days from initial post date)
3. jon smith 555.555.1212 + call for office visit (84 days from initial post date)

This should repeat:

4. jon smith 555.555.1212 + call for lunch meeting (112 days from initial post date)
5. jon smith 555.555.1212 + email info on topic of interest (140 days from initial post date)
6. jon smith 555.555.1212 + call for office visit (168 days from initial post date)

B. after the data are merged into the MySQL table, I would like take the info created on the table to automatically be exported to Google calendar with reminder dates and times.

Any idea how to do this? I know how to import a CSV file to gcal manually; is it possible to do it via a PHP page with form to MySQL to gcal, or is there a more efficient way?

If it matters, I am using Godaddy as host (linux)

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that there is an API?

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Using php you should have no problems to realise what you wish.
If you have a more specific question concerning PHP, don't hesitate to ask!

---

EDIT:

- The [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/downloads) has Google Data API support
  You can even load the [standalone files](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest) for the gdata API ("Other Downloads")
  A [Tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Google-Calendar-With-PHP-Using-Google-API)
- Googles [Samples](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/Samples) page
- [Google-Calendar-API-PHP-Class](https://github.com/montania/Google-Calendar-API-PHP-Class) by Montaia

Comment: yes, I know that api exists, however it will take me some time to figure out. does anyone have a working example?

Comment: Added some Google search results to my answer ;)